# Laravel: php match does not seem to be working

Tags: php, laravel, enums, match, laravel-9

I'm working on a Laravel app. I've created an enum like this:

```
<?php

namespace Domain\Order\Enums;

use Domain\Order\Models\Order;

enum OrderStatuses : string
{
    case New           = 'new';
    case Pending       = 'pending';
    case Canceled      = 'canceled';
    case Paid          = 'paid';
    case PaymentFailed = 'payment-failed';

    public function createOrderStatus(Order $order) : OrderStatus
    {
        return match($this) {
            OrderStatuses::Pending       => new PendingOrderStatus($order),
            OrderStatuses::Canceled      => new CanceledOrderStatus($order),
            OrderStatuses::Paid          => new PaidOrderStatus($order),
            OrderStatuses::PaymentFailed => new PaymentFailedOrderStatus($order),
            default                      => new NewOrderStatus($order)
        };
    }
}
```

In my order model I've got the following attribute:

```
protected function status(): Attribute
    {
        return new Attribute(
            get: fn(string $value) =>
                OrderStatuses::from($value)->createOrderStatus($this),
        );
    }
```

which as you can see receives some data and returns an Order status.

Now, I've got the following piece of code:

```
$order = Order::find($orderID);

        $newOrder = match ($order->status) {
            OrderStatuses::New => (new NewToPaidTransition)->execute($order),
            NewOrderStatus::class => (new NewToPaidTransition)->execute($order),
            'new' => (new NewToPaidTransition)->execute($order),
            default => null,
        };
```

but the value of `$newOrder` is always `null`, meaning the status is not being matched to any of the elements. There should be one single element there: `NewOrderStatus::class`, I just added the others for debugging purposes.

If I inspect the value of `$order->status` while running the debugger I'm getting that it is of type `Domain\Order\Enums\NewOrderStatus` so why it is not being matched?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are testing for equality between an instance of a class and a string of the class name.

Try

```
$newOrder = match (get_class($order->status)) {
    OrderStatuses::New => (new NewToPaidTransition)->execute($order),
    NewOrderStatus::class => (new NewToPaidTransition)->execute($order),
    'new' => (new NewToPaidTransition)->execute($order),
    default => null,
};
```

Comment: that worked, thanks. I added 
```protected $casts = [
        'status' => OrderStatuses::class,
    ];
``` to my model thinking that it might worked without using `get_class` but it did not